# do ... while macro/function with different conditions

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
/* some calculation */
do {
  /* data acquire and calculation */
} while (CONDITION);
```

My condition looks like one of the following:

```
(( A || B ) && C )
( A && C )
```

Note that I use these conditions with different statements for A, B and C. However the pre-calculation and everything inside the loop is always the same. I use this block several times in my code and wondered if there is a possibility to put it in a define or in a function to let the code look cleaner.

Is there a nice and reasonable way to achieve the loop with different statements?

I already thought about a function call in a while loop like

```
while (DoMyLoop( CONDITION, calculationParams ));
```

But with this solution I wouldn't have the pre-calculation in my one-liner.

How can I get my code block in a nice one-liner (or more if necessary, as long as it's easy to understand and maintain)?

---

Some additional (maybe irrelevant) information:

In my loop I receive a byte array and depending on the situation I have to loop until a specific bit changes, therefore the `A or B`.

`C` is a timeout condition.

Here is some code with variables

```
unsigned char data[10] = { 0 };
long intervalMS = 0;

/* precalc */
gettimeofday( &stopTimeout, NULL );
gettimeofday( &startTimeout, NULL );

do {
  receiveCall( data );
  gettimeofday( &stopTimeout, NULL );
  intervalMS = (stopTimeout.tv_sec - startTimeout.tv_sec) * 1000 +
             (stopTimeout.tv_usec - startTimeout.tv_usec) / 1000;
} while ( (data[0] & 0x01) && intervalMS < 200);
```

The A part of the condition can also look like `((data[2] & 0x02) || data[3] == 0x12)`.

Comment: The *actual* LOC will not be less with the use of macros, not for the compiler anyway. Macros also tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain. It's also easy to make mistakes with macros, leading to unintended consequences without realizing.

Comment: You can refer to how lists are implemented in Linux kernel, they have very complex constructions in some cases, but they present a very simple interface to the programmer, for example: `list_for_each_entry()`, you can refer to this example. Although it is a single line call, it does not reduce the LOC after expanding the macro. You can find the definition of this example in **include/linux/list.h**

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that the actual LOC will be the same, but I think the code looks much cleaner if you have a reasonable one-liner instead of the same 15 lines of code appearing again and again.

Comment: So what's wrong with *functions*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In my condition I check the data that I received in the loop. I don't know how to pass a condition to a function that relies on the data created/received in the function itself. I will add a piece of testable code.

Comment: Focus on why your code is full of magic numbers rather than constants, instead of trying to make it a single line. That's an actual clarity problem. The loop is not.

Answer (score 1):

What about next solution?

```
for (precalculation (); CONDITION; somethingWith (calculationParams));
```

`precalculation ()` is executed once, the CONDITION is evaluated at every iteration and `somethingWith (calculationParams)` take the place in of the incrementation. The body of the `for` loop is empty.

Pure C beauty.

Obviously, precalculation and somethingWith (calculationParams) must become a new function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that `do {} while(something)` is equivalent to `something=true; while something{}`. The former saves a bit of extra execution in case you don't want the initialization part.

> How can I get my code block in a nice one-liner

There is nothing wrong with your code. `} while ( (data[0] & 0x01) && intervalMS < 200);` is perfectly clear to me - another C programmer.

You check if the lsb is set and you check a timer interval. The only way this code could be improved would be to explain why you check the lsb - which you can do with a comment (do you check if a number is odd or do you read a bit in bit-field etc).

Now what you can and should do, is to put the whole snippet inside a function and give it a meaningful name. There's the nice one-liner.